# Shortest path algorithm for a grid map which visites some nodes

Tags: algorithm, graph, shortest-path

I have a grid map and I need to find the shortest path between two nodes but that path **must include some nodes**.

I have thought of trying all permutations, but the map size and the number of must nodes will be variable so I would like to use an optimal algorithm.

The map will be something similar to this:
[map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2GEY.png)

```
-Dark brown square at Y18 is the start point
-Light brown squares from B20 to S20 are the end point (can make just one end point if needed)
-White squares are walls (you cannot go through them)
-Blue squares means that the point in front of it is a must-pass (for example, the blue square at q5-q6 means must pass zone of p5-p6)
```

I am going to use Java, and I will make that map a graph with connections between them (for example s10 is connected with s9, o10 and s11).

Thank you very much for your help, and if you have any questions just ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my understanding, this is a combination of two problems; you have the stating point, the destination node and the mandatory intermediate nodes. For determination of the shortest path, you would have to calculate the distance between the starting node and all intermediate nodes, all pairs of intermediate nodes, and the distance from each intermediate node to the destination. If only nonnegative edge weights are involved, this can be done with the algorithm by [Dijkstra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm).

Once all distances are calculated, the optimal [Hamiltonian path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path_problem) from the starting node to the destination node, where all intermediate nodes are used, has to be calculated. However, as this problem is [NP-hard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-completeness), it most probably cannot be solved using an efficient algorithm; brute-forcing of all permutations might be feasible.

Comment: First of all, thanks for answering so fast!
So, I need to get all the distances between every pair of node? That will give me a huge list with the distances between (0,a) and (0,b), (0,a) and (0,c)...(20,y) and (20,z) and them use the hamiltonian path with them?

Comment: @AlbertoMendiolagoitia : ​ ​ ​ You ​ "need to get all the distances between every pair of" ​ S, where S is the union of ​ [the set of must-pass nodes] ​ with  the 2-element set ​ { starting_node , ending_node } . ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ Depending on how the number of must-pass nodes compares to the total number of nodes, getting the distances between _all_ pairs may-or-may-not be the fastest way to do that, but even if is is, you could then discard the distances between nodes that are not both in S. ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​

Answer (score 0):

Asymptotically probably this won't help as you still have to solve Hamilton path, but to calculate distances between every node you can use [Floyd-Warshall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm) instead to speed things up a little bit.